# What is the active record query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables: country, gpc, and gpc_country.
gpc can have many countries and countries can also be under many gpc. I want to get the country names that are under a certain gpc.

What is the correct active record query to return the CountryNames from the gpc_country table?

I have used:

$this->db->where('GPCID',$gpcid);
$query = $this->db->get('gpc_country');

It works but it returns the countrycode. I want them to be converted into CountryNames based from the country table.

Comment: provide schema and format the question with expected output

Comment: Your question lacks information and even not showing any attempt or else

Comment: Thats not enough to understand your question or your attempt check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean but as far as I understand you want to try this:

```
$this->db->select("CountryNames")
         ->from("country")
         ->join('gpc_country', 'gpc_country.country_code = country.id')
         ->get
         ->result_array();
```

Now again, because the question is unclear and I have no idea how your schema looks like this is just a wild guess.

Comment: $this->db->select('CountryName');
$this->db->from('country');
$this->db->join('gpc_country', 'gpc_country.CountryCode = country.CountryCode');
$this->db->where('gpc_country.GPCID', $gpcid);
$query = $this->db->get();